# What is the default behavior of the Global Window for unbounded pcollections in Apache Beam?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-beam, dataflow

I have read a lot of articles recently, including the official documentation, trying to understand how the Global Window works in Apache Beam. I have read similar questions here in Stackoverflow but I couldn't come to an understanding.

Accordingly to the official docs:

> You can use the single global window if you are working with an unbounded data set (e.g. from a streaming data source) but use caution when applying aggregating transforms such as GroupByKey and Combine. The single global window with a default trigger generally requires the entire data set to be available before processing, which is not possible with continuously updating data.

So the Global Window doesn't have an ending and it makes sense since it's global. The docs recommends to use a non-default trigger when doing aggregations because the default trigger is to fire panes when the window closes:

> Set a non-default trigger. This allows the global window to emit results under other conditions, since the default windowing behavior (waiting for all data to arrive) will never occur.

I'm confused by this. The logic here would be that Global Window wouldn't be ble to fire events to the next step of the pipeline because it never ends thus the default trigger never occurs. However, this isn't what happens in a real scenario. If I read from an unbounded PCollection with a global window, the events would still be pushed downstream.

Could someone clarify this question to me? How the default Global Window with default trigger works in Apache Beam for unbounded pcollections? I'm assuming that it does not aggregate results at all and just handles the events as they arrive, one by one. I would like to be sure if that's the case.

Answer (score 1):

Default trigger is to fire when the watermark reaches the end of the `Window` based on the event time. This never occurs for a `GlobalWindow` so if you use a `GlobalWindow` the default trigger will never be fired.

But if you set a non-default-trigger, for example to fire after a certain number of elements are processed (using the `AfterCount` trigger), your elements can be emitted even for a `GlobalWindow`. See [here](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#triggers) for more information regarding Beam triggers.

Comment: Thank you for your response @chamikara.

`Default trigger is to fire when the watermark reaches the end of the Window based on the event time. This never occurs for a GlobalWindow so if you use a GlobalWindow the default trigger will never be fired.`

The point is, if you use a Global Window with an unbounded source, the events would still be pushed downstream regardlessly. I agree with you and based on the information of the documentation they shouldn't fire events, but they do fire which is the cause for confusion.

Comment: Feel free to file a Jira or contact Beam dev list if you think a the behavior is different from what's documented - https://beam.apache.org/community/contact-us/

Comment: @JorgeSouzaDaSilva what do you mean by `the events would still be pushed downstream`? Did you apply a grouping transform after the windowing (like `GroupByKey` or `Combine`)? If you did, then your pipeline should generate an error upon construction and your job will fail. If you didn't, events WILL be kept pushed downstream because the window function just assigns a separate window for each event. The grouping transform is what grouping all the events into a global window. After the grouping I believe it is up to the trigger when the events will be pushed downstream.

Comment: @JorgeSouzaDaSilva what do you mean by `the events would still be pushed downstream`? Did you apply a grouping transform after the windowing (like `GroupByKey` or `Combine`)? If you did, then your pipeline should generate an error upon construction and your job will fail. If you didn't, events WILL be kept pushed downstream because the window function just assigns a separate window for each event. The grouping transform is what grouping all the events into a global window. After the grouping I believe it is up to the trigger when the events will be pushed downstream.

Answer (score 0):

Triggers lets us decide when the window results are computed.

When we say Default Trigger , it implies to repeatable execution of AfterWatermark trigger

whereas, **AfterWatermark creates a trigger firing the pane** **after the end of the window.**

Coming back to your question ,

*How the default Global Window with default trigger works in Apache Beam for unbounded pcollections?*

If you use Global window with Default trigger,So  data will  be never aggregated because data will be constantly updating.

It will be resulting in non-firing of trigger as global window won't end.

And Yes,Your assumption is correct that it does not aggregate results at all and just handles the events as they arrive, one by one.

Reference:

[https://www.waitingforcode.com/apache-beam/triggers-apache-beam/read#:~:text=Apache%20Beam%20comes%20with%204,on%20element's%20event%20time%20property.&text=processing%20time%20%2D%20this%20trigger%20is,value%20of%20processing%20time%20watermark](https://www.waitingforcode.com/apache-beam/triggers-apache-beam/read#:%7E:text=Apache%20Beam%20comes%20with%204,on%20element%27s%20event%20time%20property.&text=processing%20time%20%2D%20this%20trigger%20is,value%20of%20processing%20time%20watermark).

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't arrive to the same conclusion when reading. In the link, there is a implementation for the GlobalWindow, but I see the author have implemented a non-default trigger. Have i missed something?